# problems with zip component in delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, zip, components, delphi-2010

I am a new to the world perosana delphi'm trying to migrate an application module delphi delphi 4 to 10 and among the problems is throwing me a message at "dxDbZipImage.pas" that tells me not find the file "AbZipper.dcu ". Actually I have no idea how to solve this. Thank you very much for your time and help, and sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your old project has a third part component called "AbZipper". If you don't have the AbZipper.dcu file, you can try to download the source for this component. I've googled and found this [AbZipper Pas download](http://www.bvbcode.com/code/1u5hef7j-1664667-down).

Comment: I did was putting on a few components delphi 2010 "Abbrevia" and refer to some libraries you have and so I spend the error. thank you very much for your time and help